# Approximation of convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

> Prove that any convex function $f \in C^1(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{R})$ can be approximated by functions of the form $f_n(x)=\sum^{n}_{i=1} \alpha^{(n)}_i|x-k^{(n)}_i|$, where $\alpha^{(n)}_i \ge 0$.

So basically I need to prove that convex function can be approximated by piecewise linear functions, I could see this through the graph of a convex function , by partitioning the interval $[a,b]$ (say) and joining the corresponding values on the graph. But I'm not able to write it down Mathematically.

Comment: What does "can be approximated by" mean?

Comment: Isn't continuity sufficient? Then again, there are quite a few different meanings to "approximated by".

Comment: @littleO $\exists$ a sequence $f_n$ st $f_n \to f$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "$f_n \to f$ as $n \to \infty$"? Should the functions $f_n$ converge to $f$ uniformly or only pointwise? (Or in some other sense?)

Answer (score 1):

Whether this is actually true depends on your notion of convergence. Say you want an approximation $f_n$ that nowhere differs from $f$ by more than some $\varepsilon>0$ (which yields uniform convergence). Then this is actually not possible in general: Take for example $f(x)=x^2$. On the other hand, your $f_n$ asymptotically cannot grow faster than linearly as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$. In other words, $f_n(x)=a_n x+b_n$ for some $a_n, b_n$ and sufficiently large $x$. Then
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \left|f(x)-f_n(x)\right|=\infty, $$
so the approximation error is unbounded. Thus you either need to restrict yourself to a compact interval or use a weaker notion of convergence.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion by approximation I meant that $\exists$ a sequence $f_n$ st $f_n \to f$

Comment: Are you asking for $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise or uniformly? The latter isn't possible as I have shown above.

Comment: I mean pointwise convergence